# How to set the info template on a wms layer

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

In arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer I can set a template for the popup window like this:

```
setInfoTemplatesObject[tooltipObject.Laagindex] = { infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate(tooltipObject.Title, tooltipObject.Content) }
layer.setInfoTemplates(setInfoTemplatesObject);
```

Is there a way to do this with a WMS layer?

I'm looking for a way to do this in a WMS layer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WMS spec does not clearly define what the service has to return from the GetFeatureInfo method, so there API function to do this for WMSLayer. [More info in this thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/205523-identify-pop-up-on-wms).